# Can a DIV's CSS attribute be changed dynamically by javascript just by knowing it's class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this div:

```
<div class="galleria-info" style="">
    <div class="galleria-info-text">
        <div class="galleria-info-title" style="">#test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have this CSS for it:

```
.galleria-info {
    width: 100%;
    top: 290px;
    left: 330px;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
}
```

What I would like to do is somehow thru javascript change the left attribute of the galleria.info div dynamically so that based on the length of the text for #test i can position the div far enough left to make room for it on screen.

I write different information where the word #test is at in the HTML dynamically and it doesn't have an ID only class.

Any clues or help will be mega-appreciated!

Comment: `position: absolute` is probably not ideal. What are you trying to do? Can you post a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two questions; I have two answers.

## Getting by Classname

`getElementById()` gets the element by its id, `getElementsByTagName()[]` gets the element by tag name, and to get it by class name, use:

```
document.querySelectorAll("galleria-info")
```

## Setting the Position

Sorry I used `getElementById` and `getElementsByTagName` instead of `querySelectorAll`.

### `right` Attribute

Wouldn't a `right` attribute be more appropriate? You could get the width of the body (or container) and subtract however much you want from that instead.

```
var body_width = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.width;
var body_width = parseFloat(body_width);
document.getElementById('galleria-info').style.right = (body_width - 600) + "px";
```

### Fixed-Width Font

But, if you are using a fixed-width font, then you can get the length of the string, multiply by the width of each character, and then set `style.left` to that minus the max distance it can reach (i.e. 300px.)

```
var str_length = document.getElementById('galleria-info').innerHTML.length;
var str_length = str_length * 10; // Or whatever the fixed width is
document.getElementById('galleria-info-text').style.left = (300 - str_length) + "px";
```

### Wrapper

This doesn't use JavaScript, which, in my opinion, is a good thing because users can disable JavaScript. You can have a wrapper div around the original div that has the following CSS:

```
#galleria-info-wrapper {
    width:300px;
    text-align:right;
}
#galleria-info {
    text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: thank you! this helped a lot! this did help me achieve the whole gambit!

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('galleria-info')[0].style.left = '300px'; // or whatever you want
```